# Can quaternions be useful for integrals?

Tags: integration, quaternions

Lets assume we want to find a closed form for $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ where $f(x)$ is a real-analytic function.

There are many techniques to find that.

Some include contour integration on the complex plane.

But I wonder : Can quaternions be useful for integrals ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/14321/arcane-engineer                    That user said something about applied math with quaternions for integral ... AK integrals or such. Help ?? Message him ?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this certainly won't be an answer, but I haven't enough reputation to comment. The first I remember hearing of the complex numbers happened in a mathematical statistics course, contour integration is one way of determining a closed form when integrating a probability density function of a normally distributed random variable. It turns out that the theory of complex analysis is surprisingly rich and interesting in its own right, not just as a tool for computing real integrals. As you probably know, complex analysis is intimately related to Fourier series and harmonic analysis. To address your question, I can't say if quaternions are useful for computing real valued integrals, as I don't know of any examples offhand, but they are certainly useful for *some* integrals due to the existence of the theory of quaternionic analysis. I wanted to mention that other so-called topological groups are useful for integration and have their own variants of the Fourier transform, etc., of which the norm 1 complex numbers (under multiplication) are the prototypical example. If you wanted to explore this further, you might check out the wiki page on [Pontryagin duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality).

Comment: When you get enough reputation to comment, try to be succinct. Your entire 'answer' essentially boils down to "they are certainly useful for some integrals due to the existence of the theory of quaternionic analysis. Other so-called topological groups are useful for integration and have their own variants of the Fourier transform."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @robert " Your entire 'answer' essentially boils down to ..." Actually, it doesn't. From the question it seemed possible the OP thought calculating real-valued integrals was the primary motivation for complex integrals, because I also, at one time, held that misconception. I addressed this purely because my 'answer' wasn't able to be posted as a comment. You then decided it was worthwhile to remind me that the submission was not an answer, which I noted, and too long for a comment, which is obvious.

Comment: Your answer was automatically flagged by the system, and I happened to be reviewing flags at the time. I don't want to be Simon Cowell about this, but I'm not going to be Paula Abdul either.

Comment: Is the Pontryagin duality not related ?